# Prove that the proposition $p\to(q\to(p\wedge q))$ is a tautology by using identities.

Tags: propositional-calculus

This is a homework question that I am struggling with.

I can use properties to expand out or simplify this proposition, but how does one prove that it is a tautology without using a truth table or some other form of concrete values? I have proven that it is a tautology using truth tables, but I have no idea how to even start doing this using expressions and identities.

Any insight would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can rearrange the proposed propositional expression as follows

\begin{align*}
p\to(q\to(p\wedge q)) & \Longleftrightarrow \neg p\vee(q\to(p\wedge q))\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow \neg p\vee(\neg q\vee(p\wedge q))\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow (\neg p\vee\neg q)\vee(p\wedge q)\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow \neg(p\wedge q)\vee(p\wedge q)
\end{align*}

where the last term is a tautology.

Hopefully this helps !

Comment: Thank you for this! Can you explain what the symbol ¬ means?

Comment: @RichardMcCormick It means the negation operator.

Comment: Oh I see, thank you!

Comment: @RichardMcCormick You are welcome ! I am glad I could help.